# How can I get the excess amount to calculate in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Edited for more information:

How do I custom number format to hide the zero? Because it the now it will show a negative number when it should just be zero.

Please and Thank you in advance.

Original question:
I am trying to have the amount more than 8 show in the cell. The cell prior to it has the amount of 8.5

The formula I have now is =IF(H11>8,"")

So as you know the cell shows nothing because I don't want to put a value between the "" due to the fact that the amount may not always be 8.5 so I need the value to be anything that will exceed 8.

Please and thank you in advance.

Comment: Refer to this article about how to use IF function: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function#:~:text=The%20IF%20function%20runs%20a%20logical%20test%20and,AND%20and%20OR%20to%20extend%20the%20logical%20test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IF()` function accepts three inputs:

```
IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

So, if you want to show any value > 8, use `=IF(H11>8,"",H11)`.

Or, if you want to show only the excess of values over 8, use `=IF(H11>8,"",H11-8)`.

Personally, I would use zero (0) instead of an empty string ("") if the cell will be used in further calculations. I'd use a custom number format to hide the zero if necessary.

---

How to custom number format to hide the zero:

1. Select the cells that contain the zero (0) values that you want to hide.
2. You can press Ctrl+1, or on the Home tab, click Format > Format Cells.
3. Click Number > Custom.
4. In the Type box, type `0;;;@`, and then click OK.
   (from https://kb.nmsu.edu/page.php?id=75233)

Comment: How would I custom number format to hide the zero? Because it the now it will show a negative number when it should just be zero.